# Изменение размеров карты

Tags: jquery, масштабирование, изображения, css

Вопрос такой. У меня есть "карта" (изображение jpg), на ней стоят точки (изображения jpg с заданным позиционированием). Есть возможность эту карту "таскать" мышкой внутри контейнера, реализовано с помощью jquery draggable.

Теперь появились задача изменять масштаб этой карты. Я пытаюсь делать с помощью изменения css свойства `transform:scale()`, но проблема заключается в том, что после изменения масштаба draggable ведет себя неадекватно, т.е. при перетаскивании картинка смещается в произвольные места, только не туда, куда тащишь.

Может, кто-то с таким сталкивался и подскажет, как заставить draggable нормально работать с масштабируемым блоком, или подскажет для этого другое решение.

Comment: @oldy, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам понравятся другие решения:

- [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/), на примере [произвольной карты](http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/).
- [HTML и SVG: создаём интерактивную карту](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127994/).